# Application Firewall is not enabling pfctl

Tags: macos, firewall

I have a development environment that uses the [Pow webserver](https://github.com/basecamp/pow). When I initially set it up, it automatically reconfigured the firewall to allow me to connect to `my_project_name.dev` urls.

Last time I upgraded to macOS Sierra, that stopped working. Every time my MacBook reconnects to the network, I have to run `sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf` before the firewall rules allow me to access the `.dev` urls that Pow configured. From what I've read, macOS's Application Firewall is supposed to start `pfctl` automatically. Why isn't this working? Where should I start looking to troubleshoot this?

Comment: The alf should start pf, but it does so with certain oddities. Your answer might be here: [PF on Mac OS X](https://pleiades.ucsc.edu/hyades/PF_on_Mac_OS_X)

Comment: @LangLangC your URL seems unreachable from my corner of the Internet.

Comment: @LangLangC: found it back: https://manjusri.ucsc.edu/2015/03/10/PF-on-Mac-OS-X/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround which worked for me:

- System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall -> Firewall options -> Check "**Enable stealth mode**"
- Reboot
- Check if pfctl is enabled now, in a Terminal:

  ```
  sudo pfctl -s info | egrep -i --color=auto 'enabled|disabled'
  ```

Comment: Upgrading to High Sierra mysteriously resolved all my issues! I'll take your word that this fixes things. :-)