# Is the firewall really pfctl, or another instance of pfctl?

Tags: firewall, pfctl

I was mucking around with `pfctl` a while back, didn't get very far and forgot about it.

Yesterday, I couldn't `ssh` into a remote machine. I disabled the firewall in system preferences but still had the problem. When I couldn't `ping` *anything* I wondered… So, I disabled `pfctl` with `sudo pfctl -d` and lo and behold `ping` and `ssh` were working again.

If `pfctl` was still running my ruleset regardless of whether the firewall in sys prefs was enabled or not then either:

- the sys prefs firewall is a separate firewall app, not `pfctl` given a simple gui (as I'd assumed).
- the firewall in sys prefs is a separate instance of `pfctl`, both can run independent of the other.

or it's something else (I like to give myself leeway). I've checked running processes and can only find `Firewall`, no `pf`/`pfctl` etc, I'm puzzled.

Which option is the truth?

Answer (score 1):

There's no second instance of `pfctl` running.  Pretty much everything you have to do with `pfctl` requires `root` priviliges.

For example, just getting a listing of rules without using `sudo` gives a "permission denied"

```
$ pfctl -sr
pfctl: /dev/pf: Permission denied
```

Adding `sudo` allows you to view the current rule set:

```
$ sudo pfctl -sr
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble
anchor "com.apple/*" all
```

The issue you may be experiencing might be related to this post:  [Application Firewall is not enabling pfctl](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304348/application-firewall-is-not-enabling-pfctl)