# Two-way firewall (outbound/inbound protection) in macOS

Tags: security, hacking

Does macOS have a two-way firewall (outbound/inbound protection) present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It’s the [PF firewall](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/328711/119271).  It’s the same firewall that comes with FreeBSD and what drives the pfSense firewall appliance